# How can Ramadan affect my travel across Iran?

Tags: iran, religion, ramadan

I am planning to maybe go to Iran in June 2017, either for hiking (even if [I’d need some information](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82215/where-can-i-find-information-on-trekking-in-alborz-mountains)) or cycling. If I’m not mistaken, Ramadan will be from 27th May to 27th June. As a non-Muslim, I was wondering how this can affect my travel.

For example, can I eat during the day? Will I find groceries stores open by day? Will public buildings (like baths) be closed? Any other impact?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact is the country is changing in the Ramadan and making it more difficult for non-religious/non-muslims to pass the days (many Iranians don't fast and have difficulty in that period of the year).

Of course you'll find most shops open but probably many restaurants won't give service during the day. However some will still remain open for the people that are not fasting (due to several reasons: illness, travellers, ..) - as conclusion you'd be allowed to eat as long as you are not *publicly advertising* for it. That's the one thing that the religious observers won't stand and if they find you eating in the public probably they are going to warn you.

Overall I won't suggest Ramadan (specially in the summer period) to visit Iran, it will be a bit difficult but if you have to don't worry.. it has its own beauties, you will have many special foods (Ash, sweets, ..) and in the evenings you will find many people dining outside.. just keep in mind to not publicly shout you are eating and you are fine.

Comment: @pnuts well I'm originally Iranian and lived there for more than 20 years! Haven't been there in Ramadan recently. I've heard things have gotten better (i.e. less restrictions && more freedom to eat during the day) but still we should consider it's a somehow-conservative society.

Comment: Like the answer and want to add that since you're hiking and are going to be out of the city you're nearly not going to be affected at all. You just can't eat or drink in *public*. And since you're a foreigner people will take it easy on you, don't worry that much.